# Use a DrawingSurface with the 3D Starter Kit WP8

Tags: xaml, directx, windows-phone-8

The default `Windows Phone 8` `D3D + XAML template` works fine with a `DrawingSurface`. However the [3D Starter Kit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-3D-Starter-455a15f1?SRC=VSIDE) does not.

The problem is that it seems to be that the C++ is returning a  `IDrawingSurfaceBackgroundContentProvider` instead of the `DrawingSurface` equivalent.

I've attempted to change the 3D Starter Kit sample to be closer to the normal template, but am just getting errors.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the Visual C++ Windows Phone Template, Windows Phone Direct3D with XAML app, you'll see that it uses a DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid.

It's the Visual C# Windows Phone template, Windows Phone XAML with Direct3D App that uses a DrawingSurface.